# Keep control always visible

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering if anybody knows how to keep a image/control always visible when the user scrolls up and down the page.

An example is on the new Google search page that automatically perdicts your results when you type in. On the right-hand side there is a map that starts roughtly 100px from the top of the page. When you scroll down the map remains in view but is 0px from top of page. When you scroll back up, it returns to its normal position, 100px from the top of the page.

Any ideas on how this is done?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `position: fixed`

```
<div style="position: fixed; right: 100px; top: 100px; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
 I'm fixed</div>
```

Works in all browsers except IE6.

Comment: you might also need a little js if you want something similar to "starts roughtly 100px from the top of the page. When you scroll down the map remains in view but is 0px"

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` is the way to go here. If you want to achieve the described effect like on the google page, you'll need a little javascript that toggles the element's css-styles depending on the scroll position.

You can find a script for that task here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6bnuU/

Note that depends on jquery. If you're looking for a solution that  does not require jquery, you can easily rewrite the script, but you'll have to use a browser switch because IE uses a different API for the scrolling state than the other browsers.
Also note that IE 6 does not support position:fixed, so if you want to support it you'll have to emulate it with javascript (which is an easy task)

Comment: Thanks Simon, but what is the javascript to do that?

Comment: I just extended my answer and hope that it solves your problem

Comment: I must be missing something @Simon, but your jsfiddle just is doing nothing, the fixed div just goes up all the way with the content

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in that fiddle. I just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `position` with the value `fixed`, then position it on the page with `left`, `right`, `top` and/or `bottom`. For example:

```
#some_element {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
}
```

The exact example you mention also requires some JavaScript.